# fasm, объявление переменной адресом или названием другой переменной

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

как сделать так что бы обратиться, к любым данным, по их адресу, которые будут объявлены в массиве других данных

```
...
arr1   dw   1111,3333,4444,5555,'$'
arr2   db   'Privet drugi$'
arr3   db   '66','33','11','$'

arr4   db   ...;и вот тут надо бы забить адреса
....
```

получается смысл в том, что так как массивы разных размеров и разных типов, то сделать  подобный как ниже цикл не получится, если оперировать только одним регистром.

```
...
   start:   bx,arr4
...
   loopone: mov    ah,9
            mov    dx,[bx]
            int    21h 
            inc    bx
            loop  loopone
...
```

то есть в мыслях (до того как проверил), приходил следующий код

```
...
arr1   dw   1111,3333,4444,5555,'$'
arr2   db   'Privet drugi$'
arr3   db   '66','33','11','$'

arr4   db   arr1,arr2,arr3
....
```

Конечно же если так возможно сделать.

Comment: начнем с того, что адреса в принципе не могут находиться в массиве типа DB, потому что адрес занимает 2 байта в 16-битном режиме. значит нужен dw. Обратите внимание, что в DX так же загружается адрес, т.е. 2 байта и следовательно после каждого цикла значение BX должно увеличиваться на 2, а не на 1, что бы брать следующий 2х байтный адрес

Comment: @Mike, `mov bx, arr4` на диалекте fasm как раз и означает то же что `mov bx, offset arr4` в других диалектах. У fasm нет ключевого слова `offset`.

Comment: @insolor Спасибо, достали эти диалекты, никогда не знаешь как mov читать :)

Comment: По поводу второго куска кода - в любом случае вы не сможете выводить числа просто вызовом прерывания. По поводу вопроса в общем - напишите, для чего конкретно все это нужно, какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить? Возможно вам просто массив структур нужен вместо 4 массив?

Comment: уменьшить количество кода. Массив структур, это тоже какой либо алгоритм данных, который можно с помощью кода вывести циклом.

Comment: Я просто банально хотел ввести адреса в четвёртый массив, посредством написания имён этих данных через запятую. Так понял что это именно таким способом сделать нельзя. Конечно можно написать код, что бы это он делал при выполнении программы, но интересовался, именно непосредственным вводом имен данных.

Comment: @PashkaFincler, массив указателей на массивы разных типов - это не очень хорошая идея. Как вы определите какой тип данных в каждом массиве лежит? А вот массив указателей на несколько строк можно организовать, в официальных доках есть пример макроса. См. макрос `strtbl`: [**2.3.3 Macroinstructions**](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#2.3.3)

Comment: @PashkaFincler, *"Так понял что это именно таким способом сделать нельзя."* - можно, просто у вас адреса с неправильным размером данных объявлены, они должны быть двухбайтовые в данном случае.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, открыли глаза, уже который раз :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Последний кусок кода из вопроса с небольшими модификациями (указан правильный размер для массива указателей) успешно компилируется:

```
use16
; ...
arr1   dw   1111,3333,4444,5555,'$'
arr2   db   'Privet drugi$'
arr3   db   '66','33','11','$'

arr4   dw   arr1,arr2,arr3
; ....
```

> ```
> >fasm test.asm
> flat assembler  version 1.71.64  (1048576 kilobytes memory)
> 1 passes, 36 bytes.
> ```

Скомпилируется даже если массив указателей объявить первым - просто компиляция будет выполняться в два прохода:

```
use16
; ...
arr4   dw   arr1,arr2,arr3

arr1   dw   1111,3333,4444,5555,'$'
arr2   db   'Privet drugi$'
arr3   db   '66','33','11','$'
; ....
```

> ```
> >fasm test.asm
> flat assembler  version 1.71.64  (1048576 kilobytes memory)
> 2 passes, 36 bytes.
> ```